# Im keep on getting an error trying to make a session variable

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am working on a Alexa skill. Currently, I am trying to get the users name and have it as a session variable. But, whenever I go to test it, it gives me this error:

```
"errorMessage": "RequestId: 98b4fce1-9699-11e7-a585-43e1799b56fe Process 
exited before completing request"
```

Here is the TypeError in the log:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'slots' of undefined
```

Here is my code:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
   var alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
   alexa.APP_ID = APP_ID;
   alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
   alexa.dynamoDBTableName = 'usersName';
   alexa.execute();
};

var handlers = {

   'LaunchRequest': function () {
      this.emit('LaunchIntent');
   },

   'LaunchIntent': function () {
      this.atttributes['myName'] = this.event.request.intent.slots.myName.value
      this.emit(':ask', 'Hi! Welcome to Welcoming Alarm! What is your name?');
   },

   'RemebmberNameIntent': function () {
      this.emit(':tell,', 'Hi there!' + this.atttributes['myName']);
   },
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to access slots from within a `LaunchRequest`.
There is no intent mapping for a `LaunchRequest`, and slots are a part of intents. That means there will be no `intent` object inside a `LaunchRequest` JSON payload.

> A `LaunchRequest` is an object that represents that a user made a
>   request to an Alexa skill, but did not provide a specific intent.

More on Alexa requests types [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-types-reference.html).

In order to make this work, create another intent where in the users can actually say their name. (I hope you have one) Then store the name  to session attributes from there.

```
'TellMyNameIntent': function () {
      this.atttributes['myName'] = this.event.request.intent.slots.myName.value
      this.emit(':ask', 'Okay, Got it, I will remember your name.');
},
```